# Expose private dependencies to selected targets in CMake

Tags: cmake, build, target

I have `library` target with private dependencies which are not exposed through the public API. I also have `testing` target to unit-test the library -- it should have access to all of the library's headers, even the ones not exposed through the public API. Because of it, I need to link `testing` to `library`'s private dependencies. How can I achieve this apart from manually specifying them all?

Speaking in OOP terms, I would like `library` either to have its private dependencies protected so that `testing` can "inherit" from `library` and access them or to have `testing` as a "friend" so it can exclusively access the private dependencies.

Alternatively, I would like to temporarily make all `library`'s dependencies public, link `library` to `testing` (with all of its dependencies now public), and make them private again.

Comment: Just add a interface library that comes with all this info. If you create this lib in the same `CMakeLists.txt` as the original library, you can easily use variables to avoid duplications...

Comment: @fabian Do you propose creating an independent target that copies `library` but makes all includes and dependencies public? I thought about this, but 1) it's pretty verbose even with variables (I have to manually specify same sources, properties, includes, and dependencies), 2) it creates a target that will be visible to users of the project while only intended to be used internally. So I hoped there would be another way.

Comment: Something like `add_library(my_library_private INTERFACE) target_link_libraries(my_library_private INTERFACE my_library) target_include_directories(my_library_private INTERFACE my_library_private_include) ...` is what I'm suggesting. If there's really too much duplication going on, you could create a function that applies changes to a target provided as parameter. As for users gaining access to the lib: I'd recommend encouraging the use of the lib after installing it via cmake and simply providing cmake configuration scripts not containing any mention of the private stuff.

Comment: You wouldn't add `install` instructions for private headers anyways...

Comment: There is no "protected" linkage in CMake. And there is no way to declare "temporary" interface. All consumers of your library are treated equally by CMake. So for make your tests to access to private part of your library you need to manually repeat private properties (or move these properties to a macro/function, and repeat call to that macro/function).

Comment: Okay, thank you all for your answers, seems like this is the only way...